# Intelligently merging dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to merge some dicts on some specific requirements, here is some example data

```
data = [{"nid": 363, "cid": "509cd9aaad4d5", "count": 57, "value": 12.5},
        {"nid": 363, "cid": "509cd9aaad4d5", "count": 57, "value": 22},
        {"nid": 363, "cid": "cd9aaad4d5", "count": 57, "value": 49},
        {"nid": 570, "cid": "cd9aaad4d5", "count": 58, "value": 62},
    ]
```

I need to merge all the dict's that share the same `nid` and `cid` and sum the `value`, but leave the `count` as it is.

So the above example would be returned as (or similar, I did it by hand it might have a mistake)

```
[
    {'count': 58, 'value': 62, 'nid': 570, 'cid': 'cd9aaad4d5'},
    {'count': 57, 'value': 34.5, 'nid': 363, 'cid': '509cd9aaad4d5'},
    {'count': 57, 'value': 49, 'nid': 363, 'cid': 'cd9aaad4d5'}
]
```

My code attempt so far is ugly, and I could really do with some guidance,

```
tmp = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0]))
for d in data:
    tmp[d["nid"]][d["cid"]][1] = d["count"]
    tmp[d["nid"]][d["cid"]][0] += d["value"]

print tmp

new_data = []

for key in tmp:
    for cid in tmp[key]:
        new_data.append({"nid": key, "cid": cid, "count": tmp[key][cid][1], "value": tmp[key][cid][0]})

print new_data
```

Can anyone help me identify a far cleaner, and more intelligent way of merging the list of dicts.

Comment: Why not use the `(nid, cid)` pair as a tuple key?

Comment: Because I am blind, and made of fool.

Comment: Presumably order is not that important.

Comment: Order does not matter.

Comment: what happens if different values of `count` for a given `nid, cid` tuple are met?

Comment: There will *never* be a different count when `nid, cid` match another pair, meaning two dicts that share the same `nid, cid` will _always_ have the same count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve a little on your attempt by using a compound key:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

tmp = defaultdict(lambda: {'value': 0})
for d in data:
    tmp[d["nid"], d["cid"]]['count'] = d["count"]
    tmp[d["nid"], d["cid"]]['value'] += d["value"]

new_data = [{'nid': nid, 'cid': cid, 'count': v['count'], 'value': v['value']} 
            for (nid, cid), v in tmp.iteritems()]
```

The alternative would be to sort `data` and use `itertools.groupby()`, but because of the sort that is more costly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas`:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 s1 = df.groupby(['nid', 'cid']).sum().value   # sums of all values
 # assuming counts are the same for each nid/cid tuple
 s2 = df.groupby(['nid', 'cid']).count.first() # first element of counts
 pd.DataFrame({'value' : s1, 'count' : s2})
```

Output:

```
nid|cid              | count | value
---+-----------------+-------+------
363|509cd9aaad4d5    | 57    | 34.5
   |cd9aaad4d5       | 57    | 49.0
570|cd9aaad4d5       | 58    | 62.0
```

If you don't like the hierarchical index, you can flatten the dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'count' : df2, 'value' :df1}).reset_index()
```

Comment: That would be amazing. But I don't want to bundle an entire extra dependency / framework to solve a simple(-ish) problem

Comment: Valid point, but pandas is pretty small. If you have to do even more data transformations, maybe with subtle differences, using pandas will pay off very quickly.